# Discord command cooldown ignore certain roles in a certain server

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am wondering if i could have the command cooldown be disabled for a role on a certain server, so users with the regular role in Server1 will not receive a cooldown but normal users (@everyone role) will receive a cooldown but if a user has the regular role in Server2, they will receive a cooldown.

Comment: Are you using pure discord.py or discord.py.ext.commands?

Comment: i am using discord.py rewrite

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use an if-statement. I'm not very familiar with discord.py rewrite syntax, so here's some pseudocode:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    role = discord.utils.get(...)
    if message.content.startswith(...) and (message.author.hasRole(role) or not countdownIsActive):
        ...
```

Comment: I am using the `@Bot.command` for bot commands but i also want it so it is on a per server basis, so on Server1 there might be a Role1 and on Server2 there is also a role called Role1 but i want it so users with Role1 on Server1 does not get a cooldown but users with Role1 on Server2 get a cooldown.